# How to check if data is added to a table in LinqToSql class and date to TextBox

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, windows-forms-designer

I have a assignment to do using LinqToSql class and Windows Forms.
I need advice on how to check if data that the user entered is successfully added to a table and to write a message of success/failure to user.
Also i can't figure out how to show date in textbox form, to show date from a table and to be able to insert user entered date back to a table.
Here is my code :

```
 private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        northwind1DataContext nwe = new northwind1DataContext();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.FirstName = textBoxFirst.Text;
        emp.LastName = textBoxLast.Text;
       // emp.BirthDate = textBoxBday.Text; convert to DateTime somehow?
        nwe.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(emp);
        nwe.SubmitChanges();

        //code for checking if changes are made

        buttonDel.Enabled = false;
        buttonUp.Enabled = false;
        buttonRight.Enabled = false;
        buttonLeft.Enabled = false;


        ClearTextBox(textBoxFirst, textBoxLast, textBoxBday);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a tool that can run SQL to check what is in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try 
{      
     nwe.SubmitChanges();
     //print: successfully added to the database
} 
catch {
     //print : failure ... 
}
```